# Weird error when trying to plot with matplotlibs

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have a data frame that I'm trying to plot in a bar graph but I'm facing a weird error.

```
import pandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot

.... a bunch of code that combines two different data frames to get one data frame


df = df.groupby(['title']).sum()
df.reindex()

print(df)

df.plot('bar', df['title'], df['number'])
```

the print statement gives:

```
Action         1.159667e+10
Adventure      7.086050e+09
Animation      1.159219e+10
Comedy         2.071842e+10
Crime          3.525629e+09
Drama          8.479182e+09
Family         3.705357e+09
Fantasy        3.613503e+10
History        1.261357e+09
Horror         1.034400e+09
Music          1.963180e+09
Romance        1.273498e+10
Sci-Fi         2.586427e+10
Sport          6.863091e+08
Thriller       2.245254e+10
War            1.699709e+09
```

but then the plot code: `df.plot('bar', df['title'], df['number'])`
give the following error:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
> last)
> ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py
> in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)    2645             try:
> -> 2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)    2647             except KeyError:
>
> pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
>
> pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
>
> pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in
> pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
>
> pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in
> pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
>
> KeyError: 'Main_Genre'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> 30 print(df)
> 31
> ---> 32 df.plot('bar', df['Main_Genre'], df['worldwide_gross'])
>
> ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in
> **getitem**(self, key)    2798             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:    2799                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
> -> 2800             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)    2801             if is_integer(indexer):    2802                 indexer = [indexer]
>
> ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py
> in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)    2646
> return self._engine.get_loc(key)    2647             except KeyError:
> -> 2648                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))    2649
> indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
> 2650         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:
>
> pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
>
> pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
>
> pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in
> pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
>
> pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in
> pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

what am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Try: `df.plot.bar('title', 'number')` instead.

Comment: The same error happens.

Answer (score 2):

I have to write code to generate the DataFrame. Next time please make sure you include that in your question for conveniences.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['Action', 1.159667e+10],
    ['Adventure', 7.086050e+09],
    ['Animation', 1.159219e+10],
    ['Comedy', 2.071842e+10],
    ['Crime', 3.525629e+09],
    ['Drama', 8.479182e+09],
    ['Family', 3.705357e+09],
    ['Fantasy', 3.613503e+10],
    ['History', 1.261357e+09],
    ['Horror', 1.034400e+09],
    ['Music', 1.963180e+09],
    ['Romance', 1.273498e+10],
    ['Sci-Fi', 2.586427e+10],
    ['Sport', 6.863091e+08],
    ['Thriller', 2.245254e+10],
    ['War', 1.699709e+09]
], columns=['title', 'number'])
```

There are several ways to do this. The easiest one is the way you're trying to do, but it should be like this:

```
df.plot.bar('title', 'number')
```

[image]

There is another way of doing the same thing, which is more explicit.

```
df.plot(kind='bar', x='title', y='number')
```

Finally, if you want to use `matplotlib`, you can plot it as follows. This is sort of standard way that gives you maximum flexibility because you can adjust most of the elements.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
plt.bar(df['title'], df['number'])
plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, Christopher. The reason for the way of creating the data frame is because I had to combine two other data frames to get to this final data frame and then sum up the numbers for all the same 'titles', so I can't simply write the data manually, Sorry I didn't provide that before. Is there any way I could change the current data frame that I have to be able to plot it?            Thanks

Comment: @tommy, isn't the data frame I created the same as yours? What's the difference then?

Comment: I'm fairly new to python, but I believe it should be related to the grouping and sun function that I'm using, like the column that I've grouped with can't be used as axes or something. Because when I try the way you mentioned before grouping it graphs properly. Is there anything related to a grouped data frame that would cause this error? should I make any changes my data frame after grouping and summing?

Comment: @tommy, I think I roughly understand what do you mean, but I can't help if I don't know how your original data frame looks like.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your groupby moves the "title" column to the index.  Therefore it no longer exists as a column name.  If you look at the error message, as you have used different column names to the data in your question, it reads:

```
KeyError: 'Main_Genre'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError Traceback (most recent call last) in 30 print(df) 31 ---> 32 df.plot('bar', df['Main_Genre'], df['worldwide_gross'])
```

This KeyError occurs because the "Main_Genre" column is no longer a column, but is now the index (assuming you have switched this to "title" for your example code in your question).

As "title" is now the index, because you have grouped on it, you need to first return this to a column using `.reset_index()` to be able to use `df.plot()`

```
df.reset_index(drop=False, inplace=True)
df.plot(kind="bar", x="title", y="sum")
```

Alternatively, from reading the Pandas [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html), you can use the index as the x-axis:

```
df.plot(kind="bar", y="sum", use_index=True)
```

As can be seen from the above, if you take the first method of resetting the index, you can then use @Christopher's answer for the different methods of plotting.  If you want to keep the index as "title", you could change his matplotlib.pyplot answer for `df.index` instead of `df["title"]`, or use `use_index=True` within the `df.plot`.